# Ошибка при отправке SOAP запроса из Delphi

Tags: delphi, soap

Сервер использует проверку по сертификату. При отправке запроса, после выбора сертификата получаю ошибку

```
"Запрашиваемый заголовок не найден - URL:https://address - SOAPAction:GetMessage".
```

Проверяю генерированный soap запрос, он выглядет вполне правильным. Что может приводить к подобной ошибке?

Запрос:

```
><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <NS1:RequestHeader xmlns:NS1="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/8.6.0.6/nsi-common-service/">
            <Date>02.04.2016 19:54:22</Date>
            <MessageGUID>{1FF99D89-A093-4683-B8E4-AC76E8DAB58E}</MessageGUID>
        </NS1:RequestHeader>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <exportNsiListRequest Id="foo" xmlns="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/8.5.0.4/nsi/">
            <ds:Signature Id="xmldsig-0f4efe13-1ee4-42a3-b139-25ae3bb6d371" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr34102001-gostr3411"/>
                    <ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-0f4efe13-1ee4-42a3-b139-25ae3bb6d371-ref0" URI="#foo">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr3411"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>eXgrWAI4XI/2EHUUP2AhVs8ZL8cNLrqinerk1VifrXE=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-0f4efe13-1ee4-42a3-b139-25ae3bb6d371-signedprops">
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr3411"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>9qsLyxEb4yINDtg95mtcpkdA/wWfKpu/31TmngJyftI=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-0f4efe13-1ee4-42a3-b139-25ae3bb6d371-sigvalue">vELE7F7yTzaEBbL6G23MaDah6JpzhhG3Z6ewmDoA43qF1mgSD0R8E5tBs0QC+2Xj/sBX5C7Vuv62/bdB+h30Pw==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>value</ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:Object>
                    <xades:QualifyingProperties Target="#xmldsig-0f4efe13-1ee4-42a3-b139-25ae3bb6d371" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">
                        <xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-0f4efe13-1ee4-42a3-b139-25ae3bb6d371-signedprops">
                            <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                <xades:SigningTime>value</xades:SigningTime>
                                <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    <xades:Cert>
                                        <xades:CertDigest>
                                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr3411"/>
                                            <ds:DigestValue>value</ds:DigestValue>
                                        </xades:CertDigest>
                                        <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            <ds:X509IssuerNamevalue</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                            <ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                        </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                    </xades:Cert>
                                </xades:SigningCertificate>
                            </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                        </xades:SignedProperties>
                    </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                </ds:Object>
            </ds:Signature>
        </exportNsiListRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Приведите ваш "генерированный soap запрос" в вопросе. Дело может быть в нём.

Comment: Первый символ в запросе - `>` - ошибка копипаста, или так и задумано? :)

Comment: Правку к вопросу должен давать сам автор и пояснять что именно он ее сделал. Возможно что проблема именно в ней.